# Django RadioSelect in MultiWidget not hidden

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a MultiValueField consisting of a ChoiceField and a CharField. I now realized that MultiValueFields doesn't work well with .as_hidden template tag, so I looked at the django.forms.widgets.SplitDateTimeWidget and django.forms.widgets.SplitHiddenDateTimeWidget implementation for guidance.

```
class YesNoDateWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    _widgets = (
        forms.widgets.RadioSelect(attrs=attrs, choices=YESNO_CHOICES),
        forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
    )
    super(YesNoDateWidget, self).__init__(_widgets, attrs)

def decompress(self, value):
    print "Decompress: %s" % value
    if value:
        return [value, value]
    return [None, None]

class YesNoDateHiddenWidget(YesNoDateWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(YesNoDateHiddenWidget, self).__init__(attrs)
        for widget in self.widgets:
            widget.input_type = 'hidden'

class YesNoDateField(forms.fields.MultiValueField):
    widget = YesNoDateWidget
    hidden_widget = YesNoDateHiddenWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = [
            forms.fields.ChoiceField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES),
            forms.fields.CharField(),
        ]
        super(YesNoDateField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

This almost works and in the template the CharField is hidden (using the {% for field in form %}{{ field.as_hidden }}{% endfor %}), but the ChoiceField is still rendered. If I use a standard ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect) and use {{ field.as_hidden }}, it's rendered as a normal  field.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, 
/Martin

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not inheriting the YesNoDateWidget class for the hidden fields, but basically copying it and just switch out the widgets `RadioSelect` and `TextInput` to `HiddenInput`. Feels a lot non DRY, but it makes the wheels spinning.

```
class YesNoDateHiddenWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    widgets = (
        forms.widgets.HiddenInput(attrs=attrs),
        forms.widgets.HiddenInput(attrs=attrs),
    )
    super(YesNoDateHiddenWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

def decompress(self, value):
    print "Decompress: %s" % value
    if value:
        return [value, value]
    return [None, None]
```